# counting multiple values in a row, going trugh columns twice in a row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that look like this:

```
Name | date1   | date2   | date3   | etc..
per1 | status1 |         | status2 | etc
per4 | status2 | status3 |         | etc
```

The number of the dates columns is not fixed. Their values can either be a status or they can be empty.

I want to access the data of the dates columns for each row separately and process the data.

The output I want to achieve:

```
Name | field1 | status1  | status2  | etc..
per1 | value  | #ofstat1 | #ofstat2 | etc
```

So for I got, accessing the table at the beginning of the question:

```
$confirmed ="Confirmed";
$accepted ="Accepted";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $confirmed_cnt =0;
    $accepted_cnt =0;

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        if (strcmp($value, $confirmed)) $confirmed_cnt++;
        else if (strcmp($value, $accepted)) $accepted_cnt++;
    }
print("<tr>");
print("<td>$row["Name"]</td>"); // name   
print("<td>$confirmed</td>"); // confirmed
print("<td>$accepted</td>"); // accepted
print("</tr>");
}
```

As far as I know this should work, but for some reason it goes trough each column 2 times in a row.

Comment: *The number of the dates columns is not fixed.* ... so you have a dynamic number of columns or am I reading that wrong? That doesn't sound like good db design...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_row()` instead.
`mysql_fetch_array()` returns every column two times: as [1] and as ['fieldName']

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() fixed the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you have another error, replace your following line:

```
print("<td>$row["Name"]</td>"); // name
```

for this one:

```
print("<td>$row['Name']</td>"); // name
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even notice it